# How to read date from the form and calculate a timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp

I would like to calculate a timestamp based on the input date. I would like to calculate it from the user input (something like 12/12/2011) I guess I need a function that changes the format to something readable for php and then calculate timestamp for this date. Maybe I should use strtotime() function? Any ideas will be appreciated.

```
  $date = $_POST['date'];

 <input type="text" name="date" value="">
```

Comment: `strtotime — Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp` ... where is the problem?

Comment: Yeah, I found out after reading this that I have already figured this out:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you can use strtotime:

```
if (($timestamp = strtotime($date)) === false) {
  echo "not good";
} else {
  echo $timestamp;
}
```

Check the [php documentation](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).